# Delete user account - If user has attachments uploaded then redirect (with a message)

Tags: buddypress

this is what im doing... In BuddyPress, before delete user account, if a user has attachments previously uploaded, he or she will be redirected to their own attachments list:

```
function custom_get_count_before_delete() {

    global $bp, $wpdb;

    $user_id = $bp->loggedin_user->id;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.ID) 
        FROM $wpdb->posts p 
        WHERE p.post_author = %d 
          AND p.post_status = 'inherit' 
          AND p.post_type = 'attachment'", $user_id
    ) );

}


function custom_check_delete_account () {

    global $bp;

    if ( $bp->current_component == 'settings' && $bp->current_action == 'delete-account' ) {

        if ( $count = custom_get_count_before_delete() ) {

            wp_redirect('http://www.mysite.lh/wp-admin/upload.php', 301 ); exit;

        }

    }


}

add_action('init', 'custom_check_delete_account', 11);
```

My question is:
How do I set or inject a message or warning message before to redirect and print it after redirect on the "/wp-admin/upload.php" list of attachments?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting message var `http://www.mysite.lh/wp-admin/upload.php?message=YOUR_MESSAGE

Comment: Thanks. I just did it but doesnt print or display any message. Theres some error or message class or something to set before redirect?

Comment: Message query var display warnings with values ?message=1, ?message=2 or ?message=3 but not with a custom string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
function custom_get_count_before_delete() {

    global $bp, $wpdb;

    $user_id = $bp->loggedin_user->id;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.ID) 
        FROM $wpdb->posts p 
        WHERE p.post_author = %d 
          AND p.post_status = 'inherit' 
          AND p.post_type = 'attachment'", $user_id
    ) );

}


function custom_check_delete_account() {

    global $bp;

    if ( $bp->current_component == 'settings' && $bp->current_action == 'delete-account' ) {

        if ( $count = custom_get_count_before_delete() ) {

            $message = 'please_delete_your_media_before_delete_your_account';

            wp_redirect('http://www.mysite.lh/wp-admin/upload.php?message=' . $message, 301 ); 

            exit;

        }

    }


}

add_action('init', 'custom_check_delete_account', 11);


function custom_upload_notice() {

    echo '<div id="message" class="updated below-h2">
       <h2>Primer paso:</h2><p>Para borrar su cuenta, por favor borre todos sus Chaines primero.</p>
    </div>';

    remove_action('admin_notices', 'custom_upload_notice');

}


function custom_check_delete_account_upload() {

    global $pagenow;

    if ( !isset($_REQUEST['deleted']) ) {

        if ( 'please_delete_your_media_before_delete_your_account' == $_REQUEST['message'] && 'upload.php' == $pagenow ) {

            add_action('admin_notices', 'custom_upload_notice');

        }

    }

}

add_action('admin_init', 'custom_check_delete_account_upload', 11);
```

Please let me know what you think or if there exist a better way to do it.